# FreeMarker encoding confusion

Tags: java, character-encoding, freemarker

When I read an UTF-8 encoded template with FreeMarker, special chars are rendered correctly in the browser, although `freeMarkerConfig.getDefaultEncoding()` returns "Cp1252". If I set `freeMarkerConfig.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8")`, I see only question marks in the browser, although "UTF-8" is the actual encoding of the template file. In every case the http header "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" is sent.

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Set the content type property into the FreeMarkerViewResolver.

### Spring 4.2 example

```
@Bean
public FreeMarkerViewResolver freemarkerViewResolver() {
    FreeMarkerViewResolver resolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
    resolver.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");
    resolver.setCache(true);
    resolver.setPrefix("");
    resolver.setSuffix(".ftl.html");
    resolver.setRequestContextAttribute("rc");
    return resolver;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the case you are using spring framework and a MimeMessage to send the email try setting content via a MimeMessagePreparator as follows (I skip the mimemessagepreparator method getMessagePreparator as the important thing is how to set content):

```
// Create the message helper from the received mimemessage on the preparator
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
// ... include the from, to, subject, freemarker html generation here... text is the String variable with generated html
// Set the content as follows instead of helper.setText(text, true);
helper.getMimeMessage().setContent(text, "text/html;charset=utf-8");
```

This worked for me and browsers are displaying chars correctly when sending emails.

The implied classes are:

```
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessagePreparator;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
```

Also be sure that your workspace has a default encoding of UTF-8 for the template files by right clicking on them looking properties if you are using eclipse IDE.

Hope this helps.

Comment: 2 years later, current version and I have the same problem. I'm not using spring. I just generate the output with freemarker. Setting template encoding to utf-8, default encoding to utf-8, output encoding to utf-8 does not help. Any idea?

Comment: Have you checked the encoding of the template file? I mean, if you open the template in a text editor like notepad++ and set encoding to utf-8 you see the correct characters? If not the problem is related to the charset used while creating the template

Comment: The encoding of the template is utf-8. All settings (template encoding, output encoding) are also utf-8. But the processing result is always in encoding given by -Dfile.encoding=xxx, what is Cp1252 as default on a windows system.
My application is running in wildfly 10. I'm using freemarker 2.3.28. May be this be interesting.

Comment: I found my error. I used a OutputStreamWriter to wrap the incoming OutputStream without setting the encoding to output encoding of freemarker. Default encoding is Cp1252 or whatever I set with -Dfile.encoding. *No issue of freemarker!!*

Comment: Even if this is not something related to the problem in this post, is a good practice to avoid this kind of errors to force utf-8 as default file encoding in your IDE so youll see if a file is not encoded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The output encoding is those of your java machinery. If you create an output file with UTF-FOO, and pass this output file to freemarker generation, the output encoding will be UTF-FOO.

See [Charset issues](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_misc_charset.html).

With ex. code :

```
  Template templévénmts;
  BufferedWriter writ;
  OutputStreamWriter encodé;

  encodé = new OutputStreamWriter(
   new FileOutputStream(new File(f_dirDestination, résultat)), "UTF-8");
  writ = new BufferedWriter(
   encodé);
  templévénmts = f_freemarker.getTemplate(modèle);
  templévénmts.process(f_rootDatas, writ);
  writ.close();
```

You can also use [FileWriterWithEncoding](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/output/FileWriterWithEncoding.html) in [commons io](http://commons.apache.org/io/).

Comment: `setDefaultEncoding` is about the encoding of the input. http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/template/Configuration.html#setDefaultEncoding%28java.lang.String%29

The input is UTF-8 encoded and I tell FreeMarker that it would be UTF-8 encoded, but it works only when Cp1252 encoding is used for reading the input.

Comment: What is your freemarker version and in what context do you use it ?

Comment: I'm using FreeMarker 2.3.16 together with JAX-RS (implementation: Jersey) and, in the end, Servlets.

Comment: If you set all input ways to UTF-8, and process your template to a file on your local system with UTF-8 settings, is the result file OK ?

Comment: I did this. I set all output and default charset to utf-8. I read the template with utf-8. I processed the output as utf-8. Wrote the result to disk and got cp1252 (on windows system). When I set -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 all was fine. Where is file.encoding taken in freemarker implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it definitely looks like regardless of the fact that you think your input is UTF-8 encoded, in reality it is indeed Cp1252 encoded. Can you doublecheck, i.e. with a hex-editor. I second Istao's opinion -- try processing your template file to a local file and check the results.

Comment: I've checked the encoding with jEdit, what handles encodings very fine. The curios thing is, that it even works with the same template files on a system with UTF-8 as default encoding. So FreeMarker should use UTF-8 for reading the input files.