# Hot deploying HTML templates generates question marks in the place of chinese characters - only on CentOS

Tags: java, html, utf-8, jboss, freemarker

I am currently testing a Java web project to display Chinese characters using Freemarker templates.My development environment is Ubuntu 14.4 and the current project is deployed on JBoss 4 application server.In all templates the HTTP header "**Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8**" is set.

In my developer environment hot deploying HTML or Free marker templates does not generate question marks in the place of accented characters nor is encoding needed to be explicitly specified in the server.xml.

The staging server uses CentOS 6.3 and the applications server is JBoss 4.
Firstly in order to merely display Chinese characters properly an additional encoding related entry is required in the server.xml which was not required in the development environment.**(E.g. URIEncoding="UTF-8")**

Additionally if a HTML or Freemarker template is hot deployed into the staging server it generates question marks in the place of Chinese characters displayed in templates.In order to overcome this scenario a server restart is required after deleting the **work** and **tmp** folders in JBoss deploy.

What could cause this awkward behavior in CentOS only? I have failed to generate this scenario in the Ubuntu test environment but it could be easily generated in the staging server.Are there any additional configuration that I may have over looked in CentOS regarding character encoding?

I did refer to many questions on a similar line but decided to post this as any of these did not offer sufficient insight to the problem at hand.

**Stack Overflow resources referenced**

[Freemarker encoding - question marks in the place of accented characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559658/freemarker-encoding-question-marks-in-the-place-of-accented-characters)

[FreeMarker Not Able Display Chinese Character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306198/freemarker-not-able-display-chinese-character?rq=1)

[Freemarker utf-8 encoding problems on t.page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14938644/freemarker-utf-8-encoding-problems-on-t-page?rq=1)

[FreeMarker encoding confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434094/freemarker-encoding-confusion?rq=1)

**Freemarker resources**

[Why do I have ``?''-s in the output instead of character X?](http://freemarker.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_questionmark)

[Charset issues](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_misc_charset.html)

**Updates**
based on the suggested changes and comments I made some changes to the code

**In order to explicitly set encoding details**

```
Set Encoding in .bashrc, set the following: export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
Set in Run.sh JAVA_OPTS section : JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

**In order to get Locale details used by JVM added utility code block**

```
System.out.println("Init file.encoding= " +  System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
System.out.println("Init Default Charset=" + Charset.defaultCharset());
System.out.println("Init Default Charset in Use=" + getDefaultCharSet());
```

**Can get it locale information in FreeMarker using getlocale() method**

```
/*Encoding properties Check - Using getEncoding()*/
Locale locale = cfg.getLocale();
String encodingWithLocale = cfg.getEncoding(locale);
```

**In Freemarker init() setDefault encoding to UTF-8**

```
cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
```

**Before template operation set/checked locale based encoding details in freeMarker methods**

```
/*Specific Encoding Properties*/
  Locale locale = cfg.getLocale();
  cfg.setEncoding(locale, "UTF-8");
```

**Set Output Encoding() before output operation**

```
cfg.setOutputEncoding("UTF-8");
```

**Set Encoding in all HTML pages/templates using**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

But I have a concern regarding output stream encoding when using Freemarker in my program.

**According to FreeMarker support documents.**

> The charset used for the output stream is not decided by FreeMarker,
>   but by you, when you create the Writer that you pass to the process
>   method of the template.

and

> Note that the charset of the template is independent from the charset
>   of the output that the tempalte generates (unless the enclosing
>   software deliberately sets the output charset to the same as the
>   template charset).

I have used StringWriter functionality , which offers the required writer functionality but specifying encoding seems to be a problem.

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
Template tmpl = cfg_components.getTemplate(template,"utf-8");
cfg_components.setOutputEncoding("UTF-8");
rootMap.put("content_cdn_path", getContent_cdn_path());
...
tmpl.process(rootMap, sw);
return sw.getBuffer();
```

I also encode the HttpServletRequest and and HttpServletResponse stream with UTF encoding in the ActionServlet and that seems to offer a solution on Ubuntu 14.4 developer environment.

```
@Override
protected void process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8");
```

But what additionally may be required on CentOS 6.3 regarding the same program?

Any suggestion on how I can specify the output stream encoding or an alternative for StringWriter that could achieve the same?

Comment: At which step do the Chinese characters become to question marks? Like, are the deployed templates correct, and the question marks appear only in the output? (And I suppose you have set the `default_encoding` setting of FreeMarker, and also that the problematic text is specified directly in the template, rather than coming from database for example.)

Comment: @ ddekany - When a HTML file/Freemarker template is hot deployed questions marks are displayed in the uploaded template and on all outputs pages viewed there onwards. In order to overcome this problem a restart is required after deleting the **tmp** and **work** directories in Jboss server 4.

All problematic text are specified directly in the HTML templates and none are taken from DB's or or any other source.

Comment: @ ddekany - FreeMarker default encoding is not set as for now , but in the developer environment (Ubuntu 14.4 / JBoss 4) it does not generate question marks when similar tests are carried out as in the staging server (CentOS 6.3 /JBoss 4).

I found that it could b set programatically as given below.
 'Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
 cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");'

But I am still trying to ascertain what causes the drastic change in behavior Ubuntu and CentOS environments.

Comment: So if I understand well, after the templates were uploaded, if you look at the template with something else than Freemarker (like some text editor), it already contains `?`-s. In that case no Freemarker settings can help of course... the information is already lost.

Comment: @ ddekany - I think there is a bit of misunderstanding.After a hot deploying a Freemarker template and attempting to view the page through the web application displays a corrupted display with Chinese characters displayed as question marks.(No other text editors were used to view templates)

Now that you mentioned it I viewed the templates using another text editors and even then the templates do not indicated garbled data.

Comment: So if the file  itself wasn't corrupt and was still in UTF-8(!), then try what happens if you set `default_encoding` to `utf-8`.

Comment: You can't specify encoding for a `StringWriter` of course. The Freemarker documentation meant something like `OutputStreamWriter` where setting the encoding is meaningful. At some point the `String` in the `StringWriter` will be converted to a stream of bytes, and that's where the charset must be UTF-8. (BTW, modifying the Freemarker `Configuration` after you have started using it from other threads is illegal.)

Answer (score 1):

> What could cause this awkward behavior in CentOS only?

Possibly your code depends on the default character encoding being UTF-8.  If the default character encoding on your CentOS system is (for example) LATIN-1 rather than UTF-8, then any Chinese characters will be replaced with question marks.

If this is the problem then the solution is to use an explicit character encoding scheme at the appropriate point.

Without seeing the relevant parts of your code, it is hard to predict where the mistake has been made.  However characters being replaced by question marks is a solid indicator that an incorrect encoding being used ... somewhere.

---

Actually, there is a simple way to confirm this theory: look at the locale environment variables that are in effect when you launch JBoss.  For example, run the `locale` command.  For me, it says:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

If your locale settings are incorrect, try changing them (for the current shell) before launching JBoss.

---

**UPDATE** - Looking at your code snippets, you seem to have a misconception about `StreamWriter`.  A `StringWriter` accumulates Java characters ... as characters.  It doesn't encode them.  Then when you do this:

```
    tmpl.process(rootMap, sw);
    return sw.getBuffer();
```

what gets returned is a `StringBuffer` which contains a sequence of Java characters.  Again the characters are not encoded yet.

The encoding of characters as bytes (apparently using the wrong encoding scheme) is happening later than this; i.e. either in some code of yours where you are converting the `StringBuffer` content to bytes, or maybe in the servlet infrastructure itself.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.Just checked the locale details on the staging server.It is set to UTF-8.what additional code or configurations details would be required to better predict this error ?  


LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: Are those the locale settings in effect when the JVM is launched?  You can also set the default encoding explicitly using `-Dfile.encoding=<name>`

Comment: @  Stephen C  - I made some changes to the program based on the suggestions made by you.(Please refer to updated comments above)I believe the output stream encoding could cause some issues as I am using  StringWriter and specifying encoding seems to be a issue.